# python - OpenCV VideoWriter outputs invalid videos and with different file sizes

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am simply trying to read a video using openCV Video Capture, and then outputting that same video using Video Writer. But the resultant video is not playable and each time I run the function, although having the same input video the output video has different file sizes.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video_input.mp4")
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
width  = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) 
out = cv2.VideoWriter("video_output.mp4",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (int(width), int(height)))
count_frame = 0

if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
    print("Error opening video stream or file")

while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        out.write(frame)
        count_frame = count_frame + 1
    else: 
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note: The input video has 8000 frames, if i use a condition to only write the first 2000 frames the video writer outputs those 2000 frames in a video without problem.

Does anyone know what is my problem? This exact code use to work fine some weeks ago.

Edit: I would also like to add that I´m running this code on a virtual machine on jupyterLab. But when i try to run in other virtual machine, it runs perfectly fine. The openCV versions are the same in both VM's

Comment: How do you close your application? If you dont release the VideoWriter you will end up with a corrupted video file

Comment: also `assert out.isOpened()` because that could have failed